# Add column values at certain rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
x,y,z
1,2,3
2,3,4
1,6,7
```

And I have a column like this:

```
a
4
5
```

Column a should be added when x = 1. So it should look like this:

```
x, y, z, a
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 NaN
1 6 7 5
```

How would I do this using pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign `pandas` `object` `index` will be one of the hidden key , so we should do assign by value only

```
df.loc[df['x'] == 1, 'a'] = col['a'].values
```